# Find 95 credible interval of a truncated gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, statistics, quantile

I have a Gamma(shape=50, scale=0.1) with support [4,6]. I was able to find its distribution by dividing the full gamma distribution by F(6) - F(4).

```
p1 = seq(1,10,length=100)
d1 = dgamma(p1, shape=50, scale=0.1)

p2 = seq(4,6,length=100)
d2.full = dgamma(p2, shape=50, scale=0.1)
d2 = d2.full / (pgamma(6, shape=50, scale=0.1) - pgamma(4, shape=50, scale=0.1))
```

How would I find the central 95 credible interval of this truncated distribution (ie, d2)?

EDIT: Please note that my truncated gamma does not have the same pdf as the standard gamma. The reason is because the truncated gamma must be renormalized so that it integrates to 1 over the support [4,6]. That's why d2 = d2.full / (F(6) - F(4))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand right, what you need is the interval `(lower, upper)` over where the prob from your truncated gamma is 95%, and the prob for interval `(4, lower)` is 2.5%, and for interval `(upper, 6)` is 2.5%. If so, by straightforward algebra:

```
R > F = function(x){ pgamma(x, shape = 50, scale = 0.1) }
R > F(4)
[1] 0.07034
R > F(6)
[1] 0.9156
R > gap = 0.025*(F(6)-F(4))
R > gap
[1] 0.02113
R > (lower = qgamma(F(4) + gap, shape = 50, scale = 0.1))
[1] 4.087
R > (upper = qgamma(F(6) - gap, shape = 50, scale = 0.1))
[1] 5.9
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, the problem is my truncated gamma does not have the same pdf / cdf as the standard gamma (which is your F). The reason is because the truncated gamma must be renormalized so that it's integrated to 1 on the support of [4,6]. That's the reason why, in my code, d2 = d2.full / (F(6)-F(4)). d2 is my truncated gamma, d2.full is the standard gamma.

Comment: Yes, you can test if you integral your d2 on [4, lower] , that will be 2.5%, etc.

Comment: The problem is the quantile function for my d2 is not the same as qgamma

Comment: Yep, they are different. We have to do some math. You can get the quantile function for d2 from the qgamma, by some transformation.

Comment: @user19506: The densities are different but only by a factor which is the same across the domain of support and is determined to how much of the probability mass was left out by your restrictions. You are getting the same answer from two people. If you are not willing to take one of our answers to a coding question, then you should post a question on CrossValidated so they can assist you in furthering your education in basic probability concepts.

Comment: I am looking through the statistics behind this and will report back. It does seem that you two are correct. My apology. I'll update my solution to the thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I really like the answer by @liuminzhao but I already coded a much dirtier but perhaps complementary answer:

```
plot(p2, d2)  # you have most of the probability mass in the interval 4-6
 rd2.full = rgamma(100000, shape=50, scale=0.1)
 rd2 = rd2.full[rd2.full >= 4 & rd2.full <6]  # rejection sampling
 quantile(rd2, probs=c(0.025, 0.975))
#     2.5%    97.5% 
# 4.087765 5.897290
```

Comment: But the problem is that my truncated gamma does not have the same pdf/cdf as the normal gamma. Please see my comment to @liuminzhao

Comment: I threw out all of the draws outside your specific domain of support. The resulting sample has the density you specified (asymptotically anyway).

Comment: This answer is correct too. I picked the other one since it doesn't rely on simulation.